# django url regex doesn't match

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

Using Django 1.3 with development server

I try to connect with:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/lang/en

The answer is:

> Using the URLconf defined in
>   pruebas.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order:
>
> 1. ^admin/
> 2. ^correo/$
> 3. ^login/$
> 4. ^lang/(?P\w+)/$
> 5. ^site_static/(?P.*)$
>
> The current URL, , didn't match any of
>   these.

## And this is my "urls.py":

```
from pruebas import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *


# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'pruebas.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^pruebas/', include('pruebas.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^correo/$', 'mailclient.views.index'),
    (r'^login/$', 'kusers.views.klogin'),

    # Language change
    (r'^lang/(?P<lang_code>\w+)/$', 'kusers.views.lang'),    

)




if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^site_static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',  
         {'document_root':     settings.STATIC_ROOT}),)
```

I think that the line:

(r'^lang/(?P\w+)/$', 'kusers.views.lang'),

would match with "http://127.0.0.1:8000/lang/en" but it seems that I'm wrong.

Thanks in advance

The code in kusers/views.py is:

```
def lang(request, lang_code):
    request.session['django_language'] = lang_code
    return HttpResponseRedirect( "/" )
```

---

**SOLVED.**

The problem wasn´t urls.py config. The problem was the 'kuser' app folder estructure.

Thanks

Comment: What does your `lang` view code look like?

Answer (score 3):

If you put a trailing slash on the url it will work, as in:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/lang/en/

Comment: The $ symbol at the end means that the expression must end with the given expression. without the $, /lang/en/blah would match too. Also, try add APPEND_SLASH = True in your settings.py as described in the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#append-slash)